# How to format user's input in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

How can I force user for a formated input **name.extention**

Two formats I need to implement in my forms:

1. User can put only small letters ( Not Capital letters allowed )
   *Need for tagName field*
2. For another field, User needs to put filename.extentio like ( server.js )*Need for filename field*

How can I achieve these two scenarios in my Django forms OR Templates

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class BuildImageForm(forms.Form):
    instances = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    tagName = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**buildImage.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><label for="package">Docker Image Tag Name:</label></span>
       <div class="col-md-8">
       <input  type="text" name="tagName"  id="tagName" placeholder="e.g node_image/istiogui" class="form-control" required>
       /div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
       <input  type="text" name="filename"  id="fileName" placeholder="e.g server.js" class="form-control" required>
       /div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Your Form:

```
class BuildImageForm(forms.Form):
    instances = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    tagName = forms.CharField(max_length=255)


    def clean_instances(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instances = self.cleaned_data.get("instances").lower()
        return instances

    def clean_tagName(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tagName = self.cleaned_data.get("tagName")
        if tagName[-3:] == '.js'
            return tagName
        return ValidationError('Invalid value')
```

## Your View:

```
def your_view(request):
    form = BuildImageForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuildImageForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Or Use in valid form
            item = form.commit(commit=False)
            item.instances = item.instances.lower()
            item.save()
     return ...
```